# Removing top margin from first element using modern CSS

Tags: css, html, printing, margin

Is it possible with CSS and the **latest Chrome or Firefox** to automatically remove the top margin from the first `<h1>` tag, or do I have still have to use jQuery?

Comment: Modern, like CSS3? `h1:first-child { margin:top:0; }`?

Comment: I always worked under the impression that there should only *be* one `h1` in a HTML document... =/

Comment: @DavidThomas No you can have many h1 elements as long as they're headings of content of same importance in the page. And with the **[outlining mechanisms of HTML5](http://html5doctor.com/outlines/)**, you can use only h1 elements and still have an equivalent result to HTML 4.01 where you have to use h1-h6 (though it's not advisable for now as screen readers can't get from browsers the exact level of heading, not speaking of older browsers that are still there and will never do what the HTML5 specs says).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need `h1:first-child { margin-top: 0px; }`  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/Me5ZV/2/)

Comment: You can have many h1 elements in a page and all could be the first child of their respective parent element, not the first one of the page.

Comment: Let me just add to this answer: if you want to support old IEs, you can use the selectivzr.js library. http://selectivizr.com/ But don't use 1.0.2 version because it has some issues. Use the 1.0.3b version from GitHub.

Answer (score 3):

There's no `:first-of-page` selector so no, you can't use CSS for sure. No way in CSS to extract all h1 from a page whatever their parents and preceding siblings and only take the first one.
You need to know a little bit more about your h1 elements.

Examples:

- you can select the first h1 if it's also the (first and or only) child of `body > header` (or #header in HTML 4.01)
- if all h1 are siblings, then `h1:first-of-type` is the first one for sure
- if the first h1 is right after your main nav in a section, then `body > nav + section > h1` would select it. Or maybe `body > header > nav + section > h1:first-of-type`

Answer (score 0):

```
div#content h1:first-child { margin-top:0; }
```

AFAIK This won't work in IE6 and may be buggy in IE7.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo selectors.

```
h1:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Note that those aren't supported in Failbrowsers (IE 7 and previous), so you may still need a jQuery backup solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the h1 tag, like:

```
<h1 class="first">Your text</h1>
```

Then in the css:

```
.first
{
    margin-top: 0;
}
```